Were the idolatrous kings of Yisrael no longer Jewish?
In Rambam's Mishneh Torah, Laws of Idolatry 2:5 he states

יִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁעָבַד עֲבוֹדַת כּוֹכָבִים הֲרֵי הוּא כְּעוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים לְכָל דְּבָרָיו וְאֵינוֹ כְּיִשְׂרָאֵל שֶׁעוֹבֵר עֲבֵרָה שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ סְקִילָה 
A Jew who serves false gods is considered like a gentile in all regards and is not comparable to a Jew who violated another transgression punishable by being stoned to death.

My understanding of this law is that once a Jew worships idolatry s/he is no longer considered a Jew, but rather a gentile. Thus such a person would not count for a minyan, if he touched a Jews wine it could become yayin nesech etc.
I would like to know if, according to this opinion, kings such as Shlomo (cf 1 Kings 11) and Menasheh (2 Kings 21) would have been considered no longer Jewish.

It's not that they are no longer a Jew, they just lose the privileges of being a Jew. They would still be punished for transgressing commandments that apply to Jews.

Menashe in any case did Teshuva.

@N.T. if you ca cite a source that says that it would be a good answer but would contradict the language of Ramabam

@Harel13 Ramabam says explicitly not like that in the same halacha

Shlomo doesn't really belong in this category (see Shabbos 56b).

The Rambam writes in Iggeres Teiman:

אבל ירבעם בן נבט שחיק עצמות יענש על העגלים שחטא בהם והחטיא את ישראל וכמו כן יענש על שבטל מצות סוכה בסוכות
But Yeravam ben Nevat, may his bones be ground up, will be punished for the (golden) calves with which he sinned and caused Israel to sin; he will likewise be punished for failing to perform the mitzvah of sukkah on Sukkos.

and similarly in Iggeres Hashmad:

ותדע שצריך האדם לידע עיקר מעיקרי הדת והוא שירבעם בן נבט והדומין לו נפרעין ממנו על עשיית העגלים ועל בטול ערובי תבשילין והדומה לו שלא יאמר אדם קים ליה בדרבה מיניה לא יאמר זה אלא בדיני אדם בעולם הזה אבל השם יתברך נפרע מבני אדם על החמורות ועל הקלות ונותן שכר על כל דבר שעושין
You should know that a person must be aware of the following fundamental principle of our religion: Yeravam ben Nevat and his ilk will be punished for making the (golden) calves, as well as for failing to perform eruv tavshilin and the like. One should not say (the halachic principle) "he gets the greater punishment"; that applies only to human judgment in this world, but G-d, may He be blessed, punishes people for the more serious and less serious (sins), and rewards for each thing that one does.

So in short, no, even one who worships idols (like Yeravam) is expected to fulfill all the other duties of a Jew.

I returned and found a resolution based on Rambam's responsa (Blau ed., no. 264, as cited here) wherein the contradiction between the halacha cited in the OP and Laws of Repentance 3:14 is resolved by Rambam as follows

One of the texts states 'they are never accepted as penitents.' I.e., We do not accept their repentance and do not see them as falling under the category of penitents, but, rather, continue to see them as the sectarians they were, and assume that the righteousness of their behavior is motivated by fear or a desire to fool people. But the second text states that if they truthfully repented in all that concerns their relationship with their Creator, they have a share in the world to come. This [second] law concerns their relationship with their Creator, while the first concerns their relationship with other human beings.

It would seem from this that though these kings would have to be treated by their fellow Jews as if they were not Jewish, if they repented they would in fact continue to be Jews. However, it stands to reason that until such time as they repent, both in the view of Heaven and Man they would be viewed as as Non-Jew.
